# Indexing on Local Secondary Index in Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

Say, I have a table with 5 columns :- A, B, C, D, E. A is a hash key and B is a sort Key. Now, I also wanted to query for A and C. Then, adding C as a local secondary index would be fine, right? I am asking because local secondary index is primarily for range queries. For my case, it would be equal query on C attribute.

Any suggestions you could give would be greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this. I can create a local secondary index for with A as hash key and C as range key. But I need to make sure to create this index while creating the table since one can't create LSIs after table creation.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. With a Local seconday index you cannot change the partition key.  Using this you can query =

Answer (score 0):

You can query with secondary indexs:

```
let params = {
    TableName: 'users',
    KeyConditionExpression: "#_id = :_id",
    IndexName: "_id-index",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#_id": "_id"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":_id":userId
    }
};
```

use document.query method